# Onedit non contiguous range problem

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have an OnEdit function, when it is trigger I need to make some operations on the modified cells.
Currently my code is going well when I have one modified cell or a contiguous range of modified cells because I can use simple function on my range value from OnEdit.

Now it is possible that multiple non contiguous cells can be modified at same time. When it's working like that my OnEdit range is not working anymore. I need to find a solution to get the non contiguous range or the cells that have been modified.

I have no idea if it is possible but nothing is working at the moment.

Here is my code using the range value of OnEdit function :

[image: Code]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please do not post screenshots of code but a correctly formatted text copy of code. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/13045193) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi and welcome. You said "Now it is possible that multiple non contiguous cells can be modified at same time." Um... I'm no expert but I can't imagine how multiple non contiguous cells could be modified at same time. Would you please give an example of how this happens in your scenario.

Comment: Event Objects: you confuse #1-argument passed to function by Event Object with #2-information contained in Event Object. The argument is often written as `e` or `event`; you used `range` which is OK BUT it is **NOT** the same as the range returned by the Event Object. Run `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(range))` to see the Event Objects and their values. "var row = range.getRow()"=bad, `var row = range.range.rowStart`=good: "range#1"=the argument, "range#2"=the Event Object, rowStart=specific object/value. Read [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit).